# Loader not triggering while the application runs

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I'm new to WPF and building an app, using Mahapps ProgressRing control to show a loading animation during login process and subsequent data retrieval.

My problem is that the loader isn't showing, no matter what I try.

My ViewModel has a property to bind the ProgressRing IsActive flag:

```
private bool loaderActive;
    public bool LoaderActive
    {
        get { return loaderActive; }
        set
        {
            loaderActive = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("LoaderActive");
        }
    }
```

The XAML control in the view:

```
<Controls:ProgressRing IsActive="{Binding LoaderActive}" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
```

The method in the same ViewModel, which fires from a button command has the `loaderActive` flag set to `true` and then defines a `BackgroundWorker` to deal with the processes, during which I want the loader to show:

```
private void Login()
    {
        loaderActive = true;

        bwLogin = new BackgroundWorker();
        bwLogin.DoWork += BwLogin_DoWork;
        bwLogin.RunWorkerCompleted += BwLogin_RunWorkerCompleted;

        if (!bwLogin.IsBusy)
            bwLogin.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

The method fires and calls the DoWork part:

```
private void BwLogin_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000); // making sure this takes longer
        var token = ServerDataRepo.GetAuthorizationToken(userName, password);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token.Token))
        {
            GetServerList(token.Token);
        }
    }
```

Finally, I disable the loader in the other event:

```
private void BwLogin_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        loaderActive = false;
    }
```

My ViewModel inherits from:

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And the loader isn't showing when it's supposed to. I've tried TwoWay binding in XAML (which shouldn't be necessary anyway), tried implementing offloading process to another thread using `async Task` methods instead of BackgroundWorker, tried enabling the loader `loaderActive = true;` in ViewModel constructor, just to make sure it actually works - it does, so the binding works.

I also tried substituting the control with a simple `TextBLock`, with its text value bound to a ViewModel property, which I then populate in a similar manner - that doesn't show either.

The UI thread isn't locked - I checked. And as far as I can tell, I'm setting the `loaderActive` property in the UI thread - I'm not using BackgroundWorker anywhere else except for this.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that a property setter is executed only during an assignment of a value to the property. Doing an assignment directly to the backing field of a property will not execute the property setter (naturally, as the property itself isn't involved if you directly manipulate a field). If the property setter is not executed, the PropertyChangedEvent is not raised, and thus the binding doesn't update ProgressRing.IsActive...

Comment: @elgonzo That did it.. feel like a right jackass. Thank you ! :)

Comment: By the way, since it is rather easy to overlook the small difference between `LoaderActive` and `loaderActive`, it is usually recommended to make the field name visually more distinct from its associated property name, for example like `_loaderActive` or `loaderActiveBackingField`. This should make it more obvious at a glance when you are accessing the backing field (intentionally or not) and when you are accessing the property...

Answer (score 1):

Solution provided by elgonzo:

> Note that a property setter is executed only during an assignment of a value to the property. Doing an assignment directly to the backing field of a property will not execute the property setter (naturally, as the property itself isn't involved if you directly manipulate a field). If the property setter is not executed, the PropertyChangedEvent is not raised, and thus the binding doesn't update ProgressRing.IsActive... – elgonzo

Changed assignment to the property `bool LoaderActive` and it worked.